# How to guard against missing dependencies in production electron app?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using electron-builder to package an application and I'm looking for a way to guard against the following mistake:

My electron app has a `main` process dependency required in production, but I mistakenly listed it in `devDependencies`. I don't notice this during development because the module is installed in my development environment.

After building the production version and launching it, an alert dialog will pop-up with an `Error: cannot find module` stacktrace.

I'm looking for an automated way to catch/prevent this mistake.

### What I tried so far:

After building with `electron-builder`, I have an automated test that launches the production app as a node `child_process.spawn` and then connects to it using puppeteer. And I have a `process.on('uncaughtException')` listener in the `main` process.

Since this error is raised from the `require` stack, it appears to not get handled by this listener. Also, the error creates an alert dialog box that blocks execution of the spawned process until the box is closed (something I don't know how to do in a CI environment) which means the test hangs and times-out without providing useful feedback.

I'm using `electron-builder` to package the `main` process dependencies and `vite` to bundle the `renderer` dependencies.

Comment: you could write a code that parse all imports in all files and check if for all of them the dependencies exist. Though that will not help when the dependency is for whatever reason not imported and executed in a different way. Do you webpack your app? i think webpack complains about errors like that too.

Comment: Use Vite to bundle your main as well as your renderer.